# Logging from inside a Customized Bad Request Response

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm capturing model validation errors using the code below and outputting a custom 400 response from the CustomProblemDetails object which works great. My question is, I want to log from within the CustomProblemDetails object but don't see how I can use DI. I've passed in context which gives me access to the services but is this the way to go? If so it appears I can only get access to the ILoggerFactory how do I log using ILoggerFactory?

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
        {
            var problemDetails = new CustomProblemDetails(context)
            {
                Type = "https://contoso.com/probs/modelvalidation",
                Title = "One or more model validation errors occurred.",
                Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                Detail = "See the errors property for details.",
                Instance = context.HttpContext.Request.Path
            };

            return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails)
            {
                ContentTypes = { "application/problem+json" }
            };
        };
    });
```

Comment: What makes you say you *can only get access to the `ILoggerFactory`*?

Comment: Mostly because when I call GetService: .GetService<ILoggerFactory>() returns and object but .GetService<ILogger>() returns null.

Answer (score 4):

For logging in `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`, you could try code like:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
    {
        var loggerFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Logger From Invalid Model");
        var problemDetails = new CustomProblemDetails(context)
        {
            Type = "https://contoso.com/probs/modelvalidation",
            Title = "One or more model validation errors occurred.",
            Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
            Detail = "See the errors property for details.",
            Instance = context.HttpContext.Request.Path
        };
        logger.LogError(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(problemDetails));
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails)
        {
            ContentTypes = { "application/problem+json" }
        };
    };
});
```